# I need help sending jQuizzy results Via email

Tags: php, email, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking to send the results from the jQuery quiz "jQuizzy," via email.

This is the code that is sending the POST to file named send.php

```
          if (config.sendResultsURL !== null) 
      {
          console.log("OH HAI");
          var collate =[];
          for (r=0;r<userAnswers.length;r++)
          {
              collate.push('{questionNumber:"'+parseInt(r+1)+'", UserAnswer:"'+userAnswers[r]+'"}');
          } 
          $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: "send.php",
                  data: '[' + collate.join(",") + ']',
                  complete: function () {console.log("OH HAI");}
                });
      }
```

and here is the simple PHP code to send the email.

```
<?php
$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "jQuizzy!";

$jsonStr = $_POST["ajax"];
$json = json_decode($jsonStr);

$body = "$json";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
?>
```

EDIT:  Sorry the issue is that I the results are being posted to the send.php page because the email is going through, but the email is plain/empty.

EDIT 2:  I didn't even think about checking the php-error logs to which I found out my server didn't have any set up, but after setting them up it seems there are no errors on the php side of things.

Comment: What is the exact problem and error you are getting?

Comment: i was totally going to vote this up because i thought you were calling jquery "jquizzy" and that would be awesome. sadly, it's really the name of some sort of quiz framework.

Comment: When I finish the quiz it is supposed to send the results to send.php and from there I am attempting to send the results via email.

I know the results are being posted because the email is sending, but it is a blank email.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` parameter supposed to be either valid url-encoded data or an object hash. What you passing is a string what looks like it might be JSON. That doesn't make any sense, but it is hard to suggest something since you haven't really said what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the data as an object.

```
data: {
    ajax: '[' + collate.join(",") + ']'
},
```

Comment: Tried this, but I am still receiving a blank email.

Comment: In the PHP file, Try `$body = print_r($_POST["ajax"], true)` and tell us what you get.

Comment: This is what was sent in the email:

[{questionNumber:\"1\", UserAnswer:\"2\"},{questionNumber:\"2\", UserAnswer:\"2\"},{questionNumber:\"3\", UserAnswer:\"1\"},{questionNumber:\"4\", UserAnswer:\"1\"},{questionNumber:\"5\", UserAnswer:\"2\"}]

Comment: [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is just for a human-readabe printout of a variable. Try your suggestion, then if it’s sending you an array, then the easiest thing to do is `$body = implode(",", $json);`.

Comment: <?php
    $to = "example@example.com";
    $subject = "jQuizzy!";
    
    $jsonStr = $_POST["ajax"];
    $json = json_decode($jsonStr);
    
    $body = implode(",", $json);
    
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
?>

That is returning a blank email again

Comment: Try loading send.php in the browser, without AJAX, but create a sample of the JSON you’re sending, so `$jsonStr = '[...]';` to replace `$_POST['ajax']`. Then use `var_dump($json)` to see what you’ve got.

Comment: $jsonStr = '{"questionNumber":1, "UserAnswer":2}';
    
    '$body = var_dump(json_decode($jsonStr, true));
**output this** array(2) { ["questionNumber"]=> int(1) ["UserAnswer"]=> int(2) }'